# mail to myself a user's submitted form - hybrid app

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to build a hybrid app, I am using jquery mobile. The app is supposed to be installed on the mobile and not a web-app. I tried doing some research but still couldn't understand how to accomplish what I want.

I want to insert a form for the user to fill (such as: mail, name, telephone, text) and I want that when submitted the fields will be mailed to myself.
I understand that it isn't possible to insert php to jquery mobile because it doesn't support it or something like that. However, I saw that it's possible to call a php script through AJAX. But I don't get how it's done because PHP is server side it has to be hosted somewhere right?

So I need to host on the web a php file and call it through the app by it's URL?
I have found a php script that does exactly what I want but I don't understand if it's useable through hybrid app.

I also read that javascript can't mail something straight to my email address, it only has the mailto function which opens a mail form.

I couldn't find an answer to that, and I would really appreciate if someone could explain to me how it works and if it's even possible.

Comment: Need to use a server or an email service like SendGrid, Mailgun etc to send mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very easy, but for a beginner it may be a daunting task to set up so ill write Plenty of Notes and Installation tasks to get you started.

Prerequisites for a Home Setup with PHP and EMAIL Capabilities. For Remote Hosting Setup I guess everything is Installed for you but may require some Cost, so for Home use and doing it by yourself the bonus is that its Free.

**1) A Spare Computer** with at least 1gig of ram and 10gigs of hard disk. if you don't have a spare one or cant afford one at he moment you may be able to  Virtualize one on top of your current computer using something like Virtual box which is free. If you want 100% live service the computer must be on all the time and connected to the Internet.

**2) A Server OS preferably Linux one**. In this example will use UBUNTU Server. Why? Because its Very easy to setup and install extra utilities, frameworks and programs, easy to manage and has all the features you will ever need and its Fast.

**3) A Mail Account.** GMAIL as an example for sending emails.

**4) an Internet Connection.**

**5) A network Cable** to connect the computer to your Router. Even if you choose Wireless over a Network Cable to connect you may need to download additional drivers to get your Wireless card Working and Connecting Most likely you will need a Net Cable first. It is advisable not to use Wireless for Such Setup for a number of Reasons such as Security, Loss of Connection (Weak Signal) etc

That's it. Total Installation time About 35 minutes. 25 mins for installing the OS and 10 mins for the rest of setup so you can send emails Via PHP.

The Setup

**1) Install UBUNTU Server** Visit Ubuntu to Download the Latest Version.

Server not the Desktop Version as its a bit slower than the Server version. However the downside to using the Server version is that you need to learn some basic commands on how to edit, copy, move, delete, change permissions of files around the server via command line. But its not rocket science.

On the good side hosting websites on Linux Server which may hold 100's of files of scripts, CSS, and Web pages, what you can do is install SAMBA server which enables you to share your web folder(s) or any folder for that matter over your Local Network or from Outside so on another PC using Lets say Windows can connect to that folder and will enable you to use all your favorite software on windows for editing and Saving those files on your Linux Server which is easier rather than using editing utilities directly on the server. takes about a minute to install and setup a Samba server. I will add that to the bottom of this Guide.

once that's done

**2) Install LAMP Server**

This will Install

Apache Web Server, Mysql Database, and PHP

Pretty much all you need to start hosting websites (Apache), have databases (Mysql) for web uses and a server side language to handle all the work (PHP).

command

(sudo is required in ubuntu in front of commands so you can run them in admin mode which is more Secure. It will ask you for your account password, before running the rest of the command)

## sudo tasksel install lamp-server

Let it run, It will Auto download the required files so make sure you are connected to the internet. The only question you will be asked is type in a password for the root access of Mysql database.

Apache, Mysql, PHP can be further configured so there is some basic learning curve for the future.

I never had to configure Mysql, for Apache configuration i usually change the Path to where my website is and some Security settings. The default directory where your web related files go into is (/var/www/html). This html directory is where all the PHP, HTML files go into. However, there's no Reason why you cant rename this folder and reconfigure apache to directly use it as your root web folder. Ill explain how to do this near the end of this guide. For PHP configuration, you may need at some point to install extra extensions  such as `php5-imagick` which is a library for editing images using PHP. There are many extensions that can enable PHP to do many things.

Halfway there

Email Setup using Postfix which is a way to send emails

command

## sudo apt-get install postfix mailutils libsasl2-2 ca-certificates libsasl2-modules

After a few moments it will Present You with Some Options In setting Up Mail.

You want (**Internet Site**) i think its the 3rd option Down. Choose this

You will then see your hostname. No action Required here, Continue

That's the Mail Done, but we need to configure some bits to it so it knows about the mail configuration

open your postfix config file

command

## sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf

add the following in the file, you can put it add the end of the file

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

you may see (**relayhost =**) already in the file. what you can do is delete that line and add all the above there.

nano is a text editor, so freely move with the cursor keys up down, delete, type etc. When you finish editing. do **CNTRL X** and press **Y** (Yes) to write and exit the file. If you made a mistake in the file press **N** (No) to just exit without writing to the file.

Almost there

edit the Postfix email Account Information file and insert (In our example Gmail account) logging information.

command

## sudo nano /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

should be a blank file, so insert

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587    USERNAME@gmail.com:PASSWORD
```

change USERNAME@gmail.com to your email account and PASSWORD to the emails password. It needs this info so Postfix can connect to Gmail and send mails

I suggest creating a new fresh email account with your App's Name.
my_app_name@gmail.com so you have a distinguished account name for sending emails through your app.

**CNTRL X** and **Y** to save and exit the file

Now we fix some permissions to the files

Fix permission and update postfix config to use sasl_passwd file:

commands

## sudo chmod 400 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

## sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

Next, validate certificates. You say what??? Just run the following command, Do you see a bunch of Random characters about 200 of them? If so that's your servers Certificate for sending Mails.

command (no further action is required as cat is the command to just list a file on screen)

## cat /etc/ssl/certs/Thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem | sudo tee -a /etc/postfix/cacert.pem

ALL DONE You can send mails now, However we made some changes to the files above so lets reload Postfix first to take in the changes.

command

## sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload

Do a test

command to send an email from the server

## echo "This is my first test mail from my server" | mail -s "From Me" myemail@gmail.com

Check did you get the mail?

If yes then you are able to send mails directly from the server

Ok now that you can send emails from your web server you need to use Ajax Post to post the form data in your java script files over to a PHP file on your web server and compose the email and send it.

Before you consider buying a domain name (mywebsitename.com) you can start testing using the WAN address of your home router.

If you don't know the current address open a browser and type (What is my WAN address)

eg.

http://wanip.info/

this will show your WAN address. xxx.xxx.xxx.xx

this is the number you put in to your AJAX requests

example

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

More info about Ajax here

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

But first we finish off completing some minor tasks

You router needs to know your webeservers IP address so it can send HTTP requests and Data to it.

How to find the Webserver IP and Routers IP addresses using Linux

command

## ifconfig

you will something like this

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:87:35:25
          inet addr:192.168.2.15  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe87:3525/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:861 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:549 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:125639 (125.6 KB)  TX bytes:63563 (63.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:3360 (3.3 KB)  TX bytes:3360 (3.3 KB)
```

You are Interested in the Ethernet Network Card **eth0** (if you have installed more than one network card you may also see (eth1, eth2 etc) and this `inet addr:192.168.2.15` is your servers address. Not Static Yet

command

## route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

this `192.168.2.1` (under the Gateway next to `0.0.0.0`) is the Routers Local Address

Please note, yours may be different

open a browser and type that in

**http://192.168.2.1**

you will be presented with your routers home page. Log in and find **Virtual Servers** settings. Should be in the General Firewall Options.

You should see a Table like this

[image]

Depending on your routers model you should see something similar. Use the drop down menu and choose WEB HTTP. Click add. The 80 80 .. that's the ports the firewall will open for WEB communication. Enter the last 2 digits of your web servers address and click Save. Your router may reboot to save the changes.

Lets install SAMBA server so you can share your web folder to your Local Network so you can access it from a local PC. In this example we use Windows.

command

## sudo apt-get install samba

After it has finished Installing edit the samba configuration file so we can add the folder we want to share in our case `/var/www/`

command

## sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf

go to the bottom of the file and add

```
[share]
    comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
    path = /var/www/
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0777
```

**CNTRL X** and **Y** to save and exit the file

i suggest checking the net for samba share configuration as the above setup does not have much security in mind. You can do much more like request a password to connect, disable guests, etc.

we change the Permissions of the web Folders to full. Although not recommended, as you have a blank web folder you should inherit normal user permissions as you create files and when you learn about changing permissions of files and directories on Linux in the future you change them.

command

## sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/

basically the `777` is spread into 3 levels of permissions and it represents binary 111/ 111/111 -- binary number (111) is in the real world 7 so READ(1), WRITE(1), EXECUTE(1) are all turned on for those 3 levels which its not very secure. I suggest you read more about the `chmod` command and file permissions to get a better understanding about its use.

It's time to give the server a Reboot

## sudo shutdown -r now

Now The Reboot is done, Lets connect to that shared Web Folder

Assuming you have a PC running windows connected to the same Local Network as the web server (Mac should be something similar but check on how to connect to a shared drive)

Open `Computer`, choose `Map Network Drive` type in the web servers IP address e.g `\\192.168.2.23\` - click `Browse` You should see the folder we shared in the SAMBA configuration file. Connect to it.

Treat that drive like any drive to save your files only this one is the root folder of your web server website(s) folder.

However on the webserver if you don't want the default html folder eg you want a custom name for your website, on windows right click on the folder and rename it.

If you do rename it you need to let Apache know by doing the following

command

## sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

change `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` to `DocumentRoot /var/www/thenewname`

**CNTRL X** and **Y** to exit nano

restart apache webserver to take in the change

## sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

do a test page

write a simple index.html webpage or index.php php page and save it in the web folder

open a browser and type in your WAN adress

here is a link on how to compose and send an email with PHP

https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Ok last note

You have everything running, but Home Routers Have Reserve IP address that give each local PC automatically when they connect to the network. Not a big issue, but its best to give the web server a static IP address

Log in to your router again and go to your `Lan Setup` specifically we want to check the `DHCP Server` IP Pool Settings. Dhcp is responsible for giving out IP address automatically to each PC in a local network so it reserves around 100 of these out of possible 253 address on a home router. We need to check the range and choose one above that range.

[image]

You should see something like this. From 192.168.2.2 to 192.168.2.100 are reserved by the Dhcp service. So logic has it we can choose `192.168.2.101` as an address for the server as this is not used by the Dhcp service. In fact `192.168.2.101` to `192.168.2.254` are free as the complete range of a routers IP address are from 2 to 254 the 0, 1 and 255 are used by the router.

edit the network file on your webserver

command

## sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

Copy what you see below, (without the `//remarks`) and delete the existing setup in the configuration file for `eth0` which is the Ethernet card 0.

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.101 //the chosen IP address for the webserver
gateway 192.168.2.1  // the routers address
netmask 255.255.255.0 // leave this as is
network 192.168.2.0 // change x.x.2.x if  you are on the 1 network. ie 192.168.1.0 some routers are on the 1 network
broadcast 192.168.2.255 // same as above
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 //check below
```

**CNTRL X** and **Y** to exit nano

Just to clarify dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 uses a Google Public DNS server to  translate web address to IP addresses. Its a general use one. You can change that to any Public DNS Address you know, but it is required because we now have manual settings for the webserver.

Reboot the server again to load in the changes to the network and lastly log in to your router and change the IP number for your Virtual server to send HTTP Requests as shown in the above Step we did earlier.

I hope this guide helps you

Comment: Wow That's the most comprehensive answer I have ever received, so thanks alot. But if I already have an ipage account (server) then can I use it to store my sql and php and such instead of turning my own computer into a server?
And if so, should I use an existing domain name I already have?
And lastly, if it's enough for me to just being able to send the forms filled by the end user to myself and not being able to send an email from the server to him, will it make anything easier?

Comment: If I understood correctly, then what I am trying to acheieve is maybe hosting some php file on my ipage server for instance and when the user fills the form and presses submit, use ajax post method to send the information to the php script? would that work?

Comment: A user fills in a form and submits It. Serialize the form or Gather each value in a variable. Then use Ajax to Post to PHP to gather the data and compile the email and send it. This is your Ipage Server which by looking at the features includes the ability of Sending & Receiving Emails. Talk with ipage support on how to do this. If they mean something else you should be able use my Guide to install Postfix to send emails on the Iserver and do the job like that. However my Guide is for Ubuntu linux and Ipage server is CentOs Linux so its different.. Check the net if it comes to that

Comment: And yes they have Mysql Support, I cant see PHP support on their site, but they say you can host WordPress sites which are PHP, so PHP should be available. They say they have world class support so give them a call, If you have direct access to the server and able to install stuff on rather than just a management Page where you have limited features then you have no problem in installing PHP, Mysql and Mail  if there aren't any in the first place.  Give them a call to clarify your questions